# how to apply it so that I can see the marker mark

Tags: java, android

How should the marker display function be implemented? First of all, please understand that I am not good at English and I am a beginner in understanding Java code.

```
package com.example.myapplication_wdd;


import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import com.naver.maps.geometry.LatLng;
import com.naver.maps.map.CameraUpdate;
import com.naver.maps.map.LocationTrackingMode;
import com.naver.maps.map.MapFragment;
import com.naver.maps.map.NaverMap;
import com.naver.maps.map.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.naver.maps.map.UiSettings;
import com.naver.maps.map.overlay.InfoWindow;
import com.naver.maps.map.overlay.Marker;
import com.naver.maps.map.overlay.Overlay;
import com.naver.maps.map.util.FusedLocationSource;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
public class Button1Activity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, Overlay.OnClickListener, NaverMap.OnCameraChangeListener, NaverMap.OnCameraIdleListener, NaverMap.OnMapClickListener {

    NaverMap nMap;
    private InfoWindow infoWindow;
    private FusedLocationSource locationSource;


    LatLng[] latlng = new LatLng[126];
    private boolean isCameraAnimated = false;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1000;
    private static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
    };

    TextView tv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button1);


        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
        if (mapFragment == null) {
            fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.map1, mapFragment).commit();
        }
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        locationSource = new FusedLocationSource(this, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }

        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(@NonNull NaverMap naverMap) {
        nMap = naverMap;
        naverMap.setMapType(NaverMap.MapType.Basic);


//        LatLng latlng_center = new LatLng(37, 127);
//        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate1 = CameraUpdate.scrollTo(latlng_center);
//        naverMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate1);


        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate2 = CameraUpdate.zoomTo(13);
        naverMap.moveCamera(cameraUpdate2);

        this.nMap = naverMap;
        naverMap.setLocationSource(locationSource); 
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);

        UiSettings uiSettings = naverMap.getUiSettings();
        uiSettings.setLocationButtonEnabled(true);

        naverMap.addOnCameraChangeListener(this);
        naverMap.addOnCameraIdleListener(this);
        naverMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);

        LatLng mapCenter = naverMap.getCameraPosition().target;


        String api = "https://openapi.gg.go.kr/Dspsnweeklgprotefaclt?KEY=d1387b0db9bc48699aeb227c5e47e323";

        DownloadWebpageTask task = new DownloadWebpageTask();

        task.execute(api);

    }
    private void fetchStoreSale(double lat, double lng, int m) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://openapi.gg.go.kr/Dspsnweeklgprotefaclt").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        J_weekApi maskApi = retrofit.create(J_weekApi.class);
        maskApi.getStoresByGeo(lat, lng, m).enqueue(new Callback<J_week>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<J_week> call, Response<J_week> response) {
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    J_week result = response.body();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<J_week> call, Throwable t) {
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(locationSource.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)) {
            if(!locationSource.isActivated()) {
                nMap.setLocationTrackingMode(LocationTrackingMode.None);
                return;
            } else {
                nMap.setLocationTrackingMode(LocationTrackingMode.Follow);
            }

        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                locationSource.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
                return;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraChange(int i, boolean animated) {
        isCameraAnimated = animated;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCameraIdle() {
        if (isCameraAnimated) {
            LatLng mapCenter = nMap.getCameraPosition().target;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(@NonNull PointF pointF, @NonNull LatLng latLng) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClick(@NonNull Overlay overlay) {
        return true;
    }


    private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {

                String txt =  (String) downloadUrl((String) urls[0]);
                return txt;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                return "fail";
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            tv.setText("");
            boolean bSet_SIGUN_NM = false;
boolean bSet_SIGUN_CD = false;  
            boolean bSet_BIZPLC_NM = false; 
            boolean bSet_LICENSG_DE = false;    
            boolean bSet_BSN_STATE_NM = false; 
            boolean bSet_ENTRNC_PSN_CAPA = false;   
            boolean bSet_QUALFCTN_POSESN_PSN_CNT = false;   
            boolean bSet_TOT_PSN_CNT = false;   
            boolean bSet_REFINE_ROADNM_ADDR = false;    
            boolean bSet_REFINE_LOTNO_ADDR = false; 
            boolean bSet_REFINE_ZIP_CD = false; 
            boolean bSet_REFINE_WGS84_LAT = false;  
            boolean bSet_REFINE_WGS84_LOGT = false; 


            String SIGUN_NM = "";
            String tag_name = "";
            String REFINE_WGS84_LAT = "";
            String REFINE_WGS84_LOGT = "";

            int SIGUN_NM_no = 0;
            int REFINE_WGS84_LAT_no = 0;

            try {
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

                xpp.setInput(new StringReader(result));

                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                        ;

                    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                        tag_name = xpp.getName();
                        if (bSet_SIGUN_NM == false && tag_name.equals("SIGUN_NM"))
                            bSet_SIGUN_NM = true;
                        if (bSet_SIGUN_CD == false && tag_name.equals("SIGUN_CD"))
                            bSet_SIGUN_CD = true;
                        if (bSet_BIZPLC_NM == false && tag_name.equals("BIZPLC_NM"))
                            bSet_BIZPLC_NM = true;
                        if (bSet_LICENSG_DE == false && tag_name.equals("LICENSG_DE"))
                            bSet_LICENSG_DE = true;
                        if (bSet_BSN_STATE_NM == false && tag_name.equals("BSN_STATE_NM"))
                            bSet_BSN_STATE_NM = true;
                        if (bSet_ENTRNC_PSN_CAPA == false && tag_name.equals("ENTRNC_PSN_CAPA"))
                            bSet_ENTRNC_PSN_CAPA = true;
                        if (bSet_QUALFCTN_POSESN_PSN_CNT == false && tag_name.equals("QUALFCTN_POSESN_PSN_CNT"))
                            bSet_QUALFCTN_POSESN_PSN_CNT = true;
                        if (bSet_TOT_PSN_CNT == false && tag_name.equals("TOT_PSN_CNT"))
                            bSet_TOT_PSN_CNT = true;
                        if (bSet_REFINE_ROADNM_ADDR == false && tag_name.equals("REFINE_ROADNM_ADDR"))
                            bSet_REFINE_ROADNM_ADDR = true;
                        if (bSet_REFINE_LOTNO_ADDR == false && tag_name.equals("REFINE_LOTNO_ADDR"))
                            bSet_REFINE_LOTNO_ADDR = true;
                        if (bSet_REFINE_ZIP_CD == false && tag_name.equals("REFINE_ZIP_CD"))
                            bSet_REFINE_ZIP_CD = true;
                        if (bSet_REFINE_WGS84_LOGT == false && tag_name.equals("REFINE_WGS84_LOGT"))
                            bSet_REFINE_WGS84_LOGT = true;
                        if (bSet_REFINE_WGS84_LAT == false && tag_name.equals("REFINE_WGS84_LAT"))
                            bSet_REFINE_WGS84_LAT = true;

                    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                        if (bSet_SIGUN_NM) {
                            SIGUN_NM = xpp.getText();

                            //addInfo(latlng[SIGUN_NM_no], SIGUN_NM);
                            tv.append("n: " + SIGUN_NM );
                            SIGUN_NM_no++;
                            bSet_SIGUN_NM = false;
                        }
                        if (bSet_REFINE_WGS84_LAT) {
                            REFINE_WGS84_LAT = xpp.getText();
                            REFINE_WGS84_LOGT = xpp.getText();
                            double REFINE_WGS84_LAT_Double = Double.parseDouble(REFINE_WGS84_LAT);
                            double REFINE_WGS84_LOGT_Double = Double.parseDouble(REFINE_WGS84_LOGT);
                            latlng[REFINE_WGS84_LAT_no] = new LatLng(REFINE_WGS84_LAT_Double, REFINE_WGS84_LOGT_Double);

                            Marker marker = new Marker();
                            marker.setPosition(latlng[REFINE_WGS84_LAT_no]);
                            marker.setMap(nMap);

                            //tv.append("w: " + REFINE_WGS84_LAT + ", " + "g: " + REFINE_WGS84_LOGT);

                            REFINE_WGS84_LAT_no++;
                            bSet_REFINE_WGS84_LAT = false;
                            bSet_REFINE_WGS84_LOGT = false;
                        }

                    } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                        ;
                    }

                    eventType = xpp.next();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }


        private String downloadUrl(String api) throws IOException {
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {

                URL url = new URL(api);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader bufreader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(buf, "utf-8"));

                String line = null;
                String page = "";
                while ((line = bufreader.readLine()) != null) {
                    page += line;
                }

                return page;

            } finally {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }


    public void addInfo(LatLng latlng, String SIGUN_NM) {
        final String polution = SIGUN_NM;

        Marker marker = new Marker();
        marker.setPosition(latlng);
        marker.setMap(nMap);

        //marker.setSubCaptionText();
        marker.setSubCaptionColor(Color.RED);
        marker.setSubCaptionHaloColor(Color.YELLOW);
        marker.setSubCaptionTextSize(20);

        InfoWindow infoWindow1 = new InfoWindow();
        infoWindow1.setAdapter(new InfoWindow.DefaultTextAdapter(this) {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public CharSequence getText(@NonNull InfoWindow infoWindow) {
                return polution;
            }
        });
        infoWindow1.open(marker);

    }

}
```

I brought a public data api with latitude and longitude values, and I'm going to show this information on my phone screen. But it doesn't show properly. It is a university task, so I did my best to investigate, but it is difficult to apply. I would appreciate it if you could help me.